# Mango Pod Group Not Displaying

Tags: coldfusion, blogs

I am working on a Mango blog theme, more specifically a sidebar pod component on it.  I built the pods the way I see them built in another theme, but they won't display.  My skin.xml file is:

```
 <podLocations>
  <location id="sidebar" name="General sidebar">
   <pod id="about">About</pod>
   <pod id="search">Search</pod>
   <pod id="categories">Categories</pod>
   <pod id="wise-words">Wise Words</pod>
  </location>
  <location id="sidebar-page" name="Page Sidebar">
   <pod id="about">About</pod>
   <pod id="search">Search</pod>
   <pod id="categories">Categories</pod>
   <pod id="wise-words">Wise Words</pod>
  </location>
  <location id="sidebar-archives" name="Archives Sidebar">
   <pod id="about">About</pod>
   <pod id="search">Search</pod>
   <pod id="categories">Categories</pod>
   <pod id="wise-words">Wise Words</pod>
  </location>
 </podLocations>
```

The actual output of the pod location is:

```
   <mangox:PodGroup locationId="sidebar" template="index">
<mangox:TemplatePod id="about" title="About">
 <h3>About</h3>   
 <p><mango:Blog description descriptionParagraphFormat /></p> 
</mangox:TemplatePod>
<mangox:TemplatePod id="search">
 <h3>Search</h3>
 <form id="qsearch" action="/archives.cfm/search/" method="get" >
  <p>
   <label for="qsearch">Search:</label>
   <input class="tbox" type="text" name="qsearch" value="Search this site..." title="Start typing and hit ENTER" />
   <input class="btn" alt="Search" type="image" name="searchsubmit" title="Search" src="<mango:Blog skinurl />assets/images/search.gif" />
  </p>
 </form>  
</mangox:TemplatePod>
<mangox:TemplatePod id="categories">
 <h3>Categories</h3>
 <ul class="sidemenu">    
  <mango:Categories><mango:Category>
      <li><a href="<mango:CategoryProperty link />" title="<mango:CategoryProperty title />"><mango:CategoryProperty title /></a></li>
  </mango:Category></mango:Categories>
 </ul>
</mangox:TemplatePod>
<mangox:TemplatePod id="wise-words">
 <h3>Wise Words</h3>
 <p>&quot;We can let circumstances rule us, or we can take 
 charge and rule our lives from within.&quot;</p>

 <p class="align-right">- Earl Nightingale</p>      
</mangox:TemplatePod>
```

I have verified that the pods are set to display in the admin, but when I load the page the sidebar doesn't display.  When I look at the source code the sidebar div shows an empty container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is only defining pods, not displaying them. This code should *also* be inside the `<mangox:PodGroup></mangox:PodGroup>` block, and will display all pods that are **both** (1) *defined*, either by your template-pod code or by plugins, and (2) *enabled* via the pod manager in admin.

```
<mangox:Pods>
    <mangox:Pod>
        <mangox:PodProperty content />
    </mangox:Pod>
</mangox:Pods>
```

Comment: Worked great.  Thank you very much adam.